# express - Use variable from controller in <script> tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

When rendering a view with node/express I pass a `locals` object which holds different information for the view.

```
else {
  res.render('transactions', locals);
}
```

I got an Array in `locals.tags` which works perfectly when doing loops in the jade view.

But I can't figure out, how I can use the array within a `<script>` tag in my view.

```
script.
  (function() {
    // some code here ...
    $("#transTagsInput").select2({tags: HERESHOULDBEMYARRAY});
  })();
```

I tried with `#{locals.tags}` but this obviously calls the "toString" method and gives me "[object] Object". When I just use `locals.tags` the script tag obviously interprets it as normal text. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Try `#{JSON.stringify(locals.tags)}` then?

Comment: that's great, now I get `[&quot;foo&quot;,&quot;fooooo&quot;]` . is there any way so it doesn't do the &quote;?

Comment: This question gets asked about 5 times each week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `!{JSON.stringify(locals.tags)}`

`!{}` is unescaped interpolation.